# Counting frequency of factor levels from attributes in a second data.frame

Tags: r, plyr, reshape, tidyr, reshape2

I'm trying to count the frequency o factor levels but using the information available in two different matrices.

The first one (I called, below, as df1) is the abundance of certain species (coded as "sp") occurring at different sites. However, I'd like to quantify how common are species traits within each site. For example, if sp 1 and 2 represent 4 and 10, respectively, of all 14 individuals found in site 1, then I can use the second data frame (df2) to quantify the respective traits each species have. The expected result of this merged_df is a four column data frame, which has site, trait (factor), trait level and frequency of that trait level on each site. Please, see the attached figure to make it clearer. I have tried some functions, such as cast::reshape and gather::tidyr, but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Thank you all in advance.

```
df1 <- data.frame(sp1 = c(4, 10, 0),
              sp2 = c(0, 4, 5),
              sp3 = c(0, 0, 3))
rownames(df1) <- paste("site", 1:3, sep="")
str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
$ sp1: num  4 10 0
$ sp2: num  0 4 5
$ sp3: num  0 0 3

df2 <- data.frame(t1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
              t2 = c("z", "x", "y"),
              t3 = c("m", "n", "o"))
rownames(df2) <- paste("sp", 1:3, sep="")
str(df2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
$ t1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
$ t2: Factor w/ 3 levels "x","y","z": 3 1 2
$ t3: Factor w/ 3 levels "m","n","o": 1 2 3
```

[Please, click here to see a schematic description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn9g1.png)

Comment: Did you meant `library(reshape2);merge(melt(as.matrix(df1)), melt(as.matrix(df2)), by.x = "Var2", by.y = "Var1")`

Comment: No. Unfortunately, it doens't work.

Comment: the data in your picture is different from the data in your post

Answer (score 0):

correcting your df1 to fit your schema:

```
df1 <- data.frame(sp1 = c(4, 0, 0),
                  sp2 = c(10, 4, 0),
                  sp3 = c(0, 5, 3))
rownames(df1) <- paste("site", 1:3, sep="")

df2 <- data.frame(t1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  t2 = c("z", "x", "y"),
                  t3 = c("m", "n", "o"))
rownames(df2) <- paste("sp", 1:3, sep="")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  mutate(sp = rownames(.)) %>%
  gather(factor,level,-sp) %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% mutate(site = rownames(.)) %>%gather(sp,val,-site)) %>%
  group_by(factor,site) %>%
  mutate(frequency = val/sum(val)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(site,factor,level) %>%
  select(site,factor,level,frequency) 
# # A tibble: 27 x 4
#     site factor level frequency
#    <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#  1 site1     t1     a 0.2857143
#  2 site1     t1     b 0.7142857
#  3 site1     t1     c 0.0000000
#  4 site1     t2     x 0.7142857
#  5 site1     t2     y 0.0000000
#  6 site1     t2     z 0.2857143
#  7 site1     t3     m 0.2857143
#  8 site1     t3     n 0.7142857
#  9 site1     t3     o 0.0000000
# 10 site2     t1     a 0.0000000
# # ... with 17 more row
```

Note that duplicate `rownames`are not allowed, so I had to set site a a column
Order is slightly different, tell me if it needs a fix.

Comment: It works perfectly @Moody_Mudskipper. Thank you so much!